# Why is my Seagate desktop HD not being detected?

Tags: hard-drive, hard-drive-failure

I purchased a new Seagate 1tb Barracuda 7200.12 hard drive 1 month ago and installed it
successfully. I experienced no problems with it until yesterday when I turned off my PC. When I powered it up a few hours later, the drive didn't appear in Disk Management and wasn't even recognized by the BIOS.

Is there anything else I can check to determine whether the drive is dead? Jumper settings, power supply, etc? I'd like to be sure the drive is defective before I send it to Seagate for replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the drive just died. Often when hardware is working then simply stops, and you have not really changed anything, it is simply a hardware failure.

You have virtually confirmed this by the fact that you no longer see it in the BIOS. You could try it in another system, but I think the chances are slim to none that it will work.

I would start the warranty process with the manufacturer.

Comment: my hard drive is making this sound....

http://youtu.be/uw12IvMcB7o

Comment: @Mohammad Adil That clearly really bad. Based on the size, and knowing what they usually have for a warranty (here in the U.S. at least), at least you should be covered, but clearly, you are not going to fix that drive. Thank you for marking the answer. I appreciate it.

Comment: My Seagate drive made the same sound after a year and then failed. I don't want to get too anecdotal, but this seems to be becoming a "common issue".

Answer (score 1):

Did it appear in BIOS before?

Did you check Device Manager just to be sure?

The large drives seem to have a high failure rate. The Seagates seem to be among the more common failures. I would suspect, if nothing else on your system changed, that the drive failed.

But to make sure that Windows is not involved, you could boot to a different operating system to see if it sees anything there. Parted Magic is a good one because it has a lot of tools that you might want later.  Ubuntu is also fine. If you have lower bandwidth, you may want something smaller.

There are no jumpers to change except speed, and if it worked before, that should not be the problem now.

Comment: yes, the drive did appear in BIOS before.

Comment: and i have tried this drive in another pc , but it isn't detected in that pc